# PyQt pyqtgraph in QGraphicsview

Tags: python, qt, pyqt, qgraphicsview, pyqtgraph

I try to put a plot with pygtgraph in a QGraphicsView but that not really fonction well. I do like this:

```
self.plotWdgt= pg.PlotWidget(self.graphicsView)
```

And for plot:

```
self.plotWdgt.plot(x, y)
```

The problem is: I know that the plot is in the QGraphicsView because I see a little part of the graph on the top left of the graphicsView but I can not see it totally (see on the link below). I would like to center it in the QGraphicsView and make it fit with it.

Result that I get

[image]

**EDIT**

simple reproductible example:

```
import sys
import pyqtgraph as pg
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QMainWindow, QApplication
from PyQt5 import uic


class MainWindow(QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super(MainWindow, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        uic.loadUi('test.ui', self)
        self.plotWdgt= pg.PlotWidget(self.graphicsView)
        data = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10]
        self.plotWdgt.plot(data)
        
         
if __name__ == "__main__":
    app = QApplication(sys.argv)
    window = MainWindow()
    window.show()
    app.exec_()
```

form:

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<ui version="4.0">
 <class>MainWindow</class>
 <widget class="QMainWindow" name="MainWindow">
  <property name="geometry">
   <rect>
    <x>0</x>
    <y>0</y>
    <width>800</width>
    <height>600</height>
   </rect>
  </property>
  <property name="windowTitle">
   <string>MainWindow</string>
  </property>
  <widget class="QWidget" name="centralwidget">
   <layout class="QGridLayout" name="gridLayout">
    <item row="0" column="0">
     <widget class="QGraphicsView" name="graphicsView"/>
    </item>
   </layout>
  </widget>
  <widget class="QMenuBar" name="menubar">
   <property name="geometry">
    <rect>
     <x>0</x>
     <y>0</y>
     <width>800</width>
     <height>21</height>
    </rect>
   </property>
  </widget>
  <widget class="QStatusBar" name="statusbar"/>
 </widget>
 <resources/>
 <connections/>
</ui>
```

Comment: please provide a [mre]

Comment: yes sorry no problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have just established that the PlotWidget is a child of the QGraphicsView which is not the same as placing it as an item. If you want to add a QWidget (such as PlotWidget) then you must use QGraphicsProxyWidget or the addWidget method of the QGraphicsScene:

```py
import sys
import pyqtgraph as pg
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QApplication, QGraphicsScene, QMainWindow
from PyQt5 import uic


class MainWindow(QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super(MainWindow, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        uic.loadUi("test.ui", self)

        scene = QGraphicsScene()
        self.graphicsView.setScene(scene)

        self.plotWdgt = pg.PlotWidget()
        data = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10]
        plot_item = self.plotWdgt.plot(data)

        proxy_widget = scene.addWidget(self.plotWdgt)


if __name__ == "__main__":
    app = QApplication(sys.argv)
    window = MainWindow()
    window.show()
    app.exec_()
```

Note: PlotWidget is a QGraphicsView and the plot_item is a QGraphicsItem.